# Got an Erro while use Auth::loginUsingId() into laravel

Tags: php, database, authentication, laravel-4

in registration form,when i am fetch data from HTML form and save data into database and then login into the system using Auth::loginUsingId($staff->id); then following error occur.
can anyone help??

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface 
Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given, called in 
/var/www/doctodoor2014/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php
```

Answer (score 0):

This method needs a user id as an argument. Are you sure that `$staff->id` is giving you just an integer (user id)? Try to `var_dump($staff->id);` , or `dd($staff->id);` , (http://laravel.com/api/function-dd.html) to see what you are getting back.

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

Comment: yes,i checked by dd($staff->id); and this method gives me id, EX. 12 or any integer number.